# only first search in "screen" after redner method works

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, next.js, react-testing-library

I can't make my search works twice into "screen" while debugging with jest and testing-libray/react. Only the first assertion is found. If I invert them the problem stay the same :

```
    import React from "react";
    import { BarChart, YAxis, Bar } from "recharts";
    import { waitFor, render, screen, getByText, cleanup } from "@testing-library/react";
    import { Graph_count_type_planete, Count_annee, Graph_masse_distance } from '../component_planet/graph_planet';
    import Dashboard from '../pages/planet';
    const useRouter = jest.spyOn(require('next/router'), 'useRouter')

    describe("Titre", () => {
          let graphContainer;
          let texte;
          let texte2;
          afterAll(cleanup)
        
          beforeAll(() => {
            useRouter.mockImplementation(() => ({
              pathname: '/planet'
            }))
            const { container, screen } = render(
              <div>
                <Dashboard />
              </div>
            );
            graphContainer = container;
          }, { timeout: 30000 });
        
          it("Titre page planète2", async () => {
            await waitFor(() => {
              texte = screen.getByText("Prout")
              expect(texte).toBeInTheDocument();
              
            }, { timeout: 3000 });
        
          })
        
          it("Titre page planète", async () => {
            await waitFor(() => {
              texte2 = screen.getByText("Historique")
              expect(texte2).toBeInTheDocument();
        
            }, { timeout: 3000 });
        
          })
```

Do you know what is the problem ?
Tell me if you need more to solve this. The only thing I can say is "Dashboard" component is a large component with sub-component.

Comment: Please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: if you add this function for the "Dashboard" component, you should reproduce the error :
function Dashboard ():JSX.Element {


    return (
        <section>
            <div>Prout</div>
            <div>Historique</div>
        </section>
    );

}

Comment: It's good practice to call the `render` method on _each_ test case.

Comment: @juliomalves You know why ?

Comment: You want each test case to run in isolation and not be affected by operations executed in other tests.

Comment: I don't understand the technic behind that but it works